# How to call a function when mouse over and not over a widget in pyFLTK?

Tags: python, user-interface, events, fltk

i want to call a function when mouse over a `Fl_Widget` and call another function when mouse not over widget. like my code which is `Fl_Input` how can I call a function when the mouse over that `Fl_Input` and not over?

this is my code:

```py
from fltk import *

win = Fl_Window(400,200)
win.label('Set Text') 

def enter(w):
    fl_message('Enter')

def leave(w):
    fl_message('Leave')

inp = Fl_Input (100, 10, 100, 20, 'Input: ' )
out = Fl_Output(100, 60, 100, 20, 'Output: ')
inp.when(FL_WHEN_ENTER_KEY)
inp.callback(enter)
win.end()
win.show()
Fl.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of the test scripts that come with pyFltk? In particular, there is one example called handle_events.py that should apply to your situation. What you have to do is basically the following:

1. Create a class in Python, which derives from the widget for which
   you want to handle events
2. Overwrite the handle method in that widget

This could look as follows:

```
class EventHandler(Fl_Input):
def __init__(self, X, Y, W, H, L):
    Fl_Input.__init__(self, X, Y, W, H, L)
    
def handle(self, event):
    if event == FL_ENTER:
        fl_message('Enter')
        return 1
    elif event == FL_LEAVE:
        fl_message('Leave')
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Note the return values: you must return 1 if the event was handled correctly and 0 otherwise.

Good luck

Andreas